# Continue the script if an element is not found using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am having a trouble trying to figure out how to continue the script if an element is not found using selenium in Python.

This code cycles through reports, finds the refresh button and then clicks on the download the button.  The only problem is, that some reports do not have a refresh button.  So, I would like the script to continue if the button is not found.

I am still new to python/selenium so that is why I am posting the entire code.  I need to know what to slip in to make this work!  Thanks in advance for the help with this head banging problem

This is where selenium will try to click the refresh button

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_updateFilters_TitleAnchor").click()
```

The complete code:

```
import time
import os
import os.path
import glob
import shutil
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

files = glob.glob('/Users/me/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS/*')
for f in files:
    os.remove(f)        

open('/Users/me/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS/report.csv', "w")

for x in range(1, 73):      
    while True:    
        try:
            fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/me/Documents/FirefoxProfile')
            browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
            browser.get('https://websitething.com/')

            time.sleep(8)

            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").clear()
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").send_keys("usr")
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").clear()
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").send_keys("paswd")
            browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_login").click()

#gets user to reporting front end

            ReportMgr= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Report Manager')
            ReportMgr.click()

            time.sleep(5)

            CustomReport= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Custom Report')
            CustomReport.click()

            time.sleep(5)

            ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management')
            ProgramManagement.click()
            ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)

#pulls reports

            browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').click()
            time.sleep(60)
            browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN * x, Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(60)
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_updateFilters_TitleAnchor").click()            
            time.sleep(60)            
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_CSVButton_ImageAnchor > img").click()
            fname = "Report(%s).csv" % (x)
            os.chdir('/Users/me/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS')
            time.sleep(60)
            #browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').click()
            #time.sleep(30)
            browser.quit()

        except:
               browser.quit()           
               continue
        else:
               break
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [`try` / `except` block to handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and continue.

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_updateFilters_TitleAnchor").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    # do stuff
```

Note that Florent B.'s answer will find multiple elements on the page instead of one.  So depending on what you need to find, and how many of them there are, it may cause minor performance issues.  If you actually need to find multiple elements, his solution will work just fine, but for OP's question best practices dictate that we use the method designed to handle the task at hand instead of the method designed to handle multiples of the same task.  It's like greedy matching vs lazy matching with regex.  If you only need the first match, write a lazy pattern and it will be more efficient, even if writing the greedy pattern still works out technically.

Comment: How should I offset the script using this method?

Comment: What do you mean by offset?

Comment: Disregard - sorry about that.  I think I need to add "pass" as my function after my except statement to continue with the script.  Agree?

Comment: @Yogwhatup, yeah.  If you _only_ want it to skip clicking that specific button, but it still needs to do the actions scripted after clicking that specific button.  If you need to skip the other actions, handle it all in the single `try` / `except` block.

Comment: this did it.  I just needed to skip that one line in the script if it wasn't able to find that button.  Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @DuckPuncher: -1, while the code is correct, the comment is not. First, find_elements would not return multiple elements, but one or zero element. A unique selector cannot return more than one element. Second there will be no performance issue since the time difference would be at worst a few microsecond higher, which is insignificant and without performance impact whatsoever. You didn't even consider that raising an exception could be more expensive. Moreover the tests I performed show that handling the error is more expensive that using find_elements.

Comment: @DuckPuncher: Third, handling an exception to find whether an element is present or not is from a functional point of view not a best practice, but a workaround to fix the lack of a proper method. So counting if there is one element makes as much sense if not more. And fourth, if the efficiency between greedy matching vs lazy with a regex were of any concern, you'd be using a tokenizer and not a regex. So make yourself a favor and don't spread incorrect information.

Answer (score 3):

You could check that at least one item is returned by find_elements:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("...")
if elements :
  elements[0].click()
```

And if you are concerned that it is more expensive than a try/catch, well it's not, so both methods are valid.

Chrome 49.0.2623 Windows 8.1 (1000 samples) :

```
        | find_element | find_elements |
Sum     | 10077.4544ms |  9895.2903ms  | diff: -182.1641ms
Mean    |    10.0775ms |     9.8953ms  | diff:  -0.1822ms
Mediam  |     9.7563ms |     9.5361ms  | diff:  -0.2202ms
Min     |     9.0264ms |     9.0220ms  | diff:  -0.0044ms
Std     |     2.2050ms |     2.4411ms  |
```

Firefox 44.0.2 Windows 8.1 (1000 samples) :

```
        | find_element | find_elements |
Sum     |  9146.3389ms |  8860.2409ms  | diff: -286.0981ms
Mean    |     9.1463ms |     8.8602ms  | diff:  -0.2861ms
Mediam  |     8.0231ms |     7.8351ms  | diff:  -0.1880ms
Min     |     6.3442ms |     6.1565ms  | diff:  -0.1877ms
Std     |     5.3030ms |     6.2566ms  |
```

The code to compare find_element vs find_elements:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from statistics import mode, mean, pstdev, median
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
time.sleep(1)

selectors = [
  '#nav-questions',         # present
  '#abcdef',                # not present
  'div.nav:nth-child(2)',   # present
  'div.nav:nth-child(10)',  # not present
  '.youarehere',            # present
  '.abcdef'                 # not present
];

timesA = []
timesB = []

samples = 1000
for i in range(samples):

  start = time.clock()
  try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selectors[i % 6])
  except:
    pass
  timesA.append((time.clock()-start) * 1000.0)

  start = time.clock()
  elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(selectors[i % 6])
  if not elements :
    pass
  timesB.append((time.clock()-start) * 1000.0)

print("\n".join([
  "        | find_element vs find_elements",
  "Sum     | {:10.4f}ms | {:10.4f}ms | diff: {:10.4f}ms".format(sum(timesA), sum(timesB), sum(timesB)-sum(timesA)),
  "Mean    | {:10.4f}ms | {:10.4f}ms | diff: {:10.4f}ms".format(mean(timesA), mean(timesB), mean(timesB)-mean(timesA)),
  "Mediam  | {:10.4f}ms | {:10.4f}ms | diff: {:10.4f}ms".format(median(timesA), median(timesB), median(timesB)-median(timesA)),
  "Min     | {:10.4f}ms | {:10.4f}ms | diff: {:10.4f}ms".format(min(timesA), min(timesB), min(timesB)-min(timesA)),
  "Std     | {:10.4f}ms | {:10.4f}ms |                 ".format(pstdev(timesA), pstdev(timesB))
]))
```

Comment: If you are only looking for 1 element, or the first element, this is excessive.  Especially if there are more than 1 element that can be found with the selector on the page.  `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` will finish once it finds the first element.  For that, you need a `try` / `except` block.

Comment: @DuckPuncher, It will return 0 or 1 elements. If there is more, then the selector is incorrect to begin with. And saying that it's excessive without measurable facts is not a valid argument.

Comment: I guess it just doesn't make sense to use a method designed for doing something different when there is a method for finding 1 element, and a clear way of handling it if it isn't found.  Your solution adds unneeded complexity, even if it is still really simple.  If I'm reading this code without looking at the website, I assume there are multiple elements based on the fact that the `find_elements_by_css_selector` method was used.  It just makes way more sense in this situation to use a `try` / `except` block.

Comment: @DuckPuncher, your arguments are subjective and pure speculation. I could also defend my point by saying that try/catch were designed to handled something that went wrong, but it would be pointless since both methods are valid and used in different frameworks.

Comment: Read up on `selenium`. Not finding an element throws an error, which clearly means something went wrong.  I'm not trying to offend, only trying to provide the _best_ solution for the question posed. Both methods work, I'm not arguing that.  What I'm arguing is that one solution makes more sense for the question posed.  If the question required the OP to not use `try` / `catch`, then it would make sense.  Using your solution is the programming equivalent of finding an item at the grocery store and continuing to check every shelf to see if it is there instead of just checking out once it's found

Comment: @DuckPuncher, again it's pure speculation. You need to bring some facts to insinuate that one is faster than the other. How do you know that building the stack trace on the client and server side is faster that checking that there is a second element? And if there were, how do you know that it's not insignificant compared to the latency? I'm not against critics, but please write comments that bring facts, not opinions.

Comment: I just timed it and got `0.0570001602173` for finding `.started` on stackoverflow.com using `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector` and got 
`0.0449998378754` using `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`. I then ran this 10 times and had similar results with `find_element_by_css_selector` being _twice as fast_ around 40% of the time.  So it's not speculation.

Comment: @DuckPuncher, First, it was speculation since you didn't have the metrics at the time, and second your conclusion is incorrect. Your tests are probably biased. I tested 1000 samples on Firefox and Chrome and found out that the dispersion is greater than the difference. It means that the difference is so slim that it's not event possible to measure it (SamplesA n:1000 μ:0.013927 σ:0.0020163, SamplesB n:1000 μ:0.0132605 σ:0.0014084, Diff: 0.000667).

Comment: How about locating every `div` on the same page?  Run that and tell me you can't time the difference.  `1.44899988174` seconds VS. `0.0380001068115` seconds shows that you are patently wrong about `find_elements_by_css_selector` being a replacement for `find_element_by_css_selector`.  Because if some unsuspecting person reads your answer and litters `find_elements_by_css_selector` throughout their code when they don't need it, they will be wasting CPU cycles and RAM with garbage data they have no concern for.  Especially when there is a simple way to avoid it by _using the correct method._

Comment: @DuckPuncher Why would I locate every div? The worst case scenario with `find_elements_by_css_selector` is 1 returned element.

Comment: Honestly, the only reason is so you can understand the difference between the 2 methods in question. It's demonstrating that your answer can easily lead to inefficient code. If the amount of elements changes on the page, your solution will take more time to execute _for no good reason at all_. Why do it that way when you can avoid the problem all together? I can't think of any reason other than laziness or stupidity considering how much the web changes. So defend your solution or stop.  I'm not going to try to educate someone who could clearly care less about doing things _correctly_.

Comment: Again this is speculation not facts. Can you even provide one real use case were it will degrade the pref? Your argument is like saying that string.format shouldn't be used because it's too slow compared to string concatenation. And if it's so wrong can you tell me why the findElement is implemented with a findElements in protractor? https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/83570f055cd5328e664a8989334ff0e87a22cfce/lib/element.js#L733

Comment: @DuckPuncher, this might also come to a shock to you but JQUery also tests the elements.length to check if an element is present (https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/). So by your criteria it is "not correct" and "wasting CPU cycles and RAM with garbage data". You should probably report them the issue. But clearly you are too stubborn or not experienced/educated enough to either admit that you are wrong or prove with facts that you are right.

Answer (score 1):

As known whenever element is not available then it will throw exception. In this situation we know element is some times not available so we need to handle this exception.

In Java, we can handle it by using try/catch.

```
 try{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-item-92']/a")).click(); //your element here
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); //printing exception
    }
```

Please make a note: if any case this element is to display but not, then still execution goes to next line as we handled exception.

Thank You,
Murali